# Что представляют собой функциональные требования к фреймворку

Tags: спецификация

Доброго времени суток.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что функциональные требования описывают функции системы, т.е. что она конкретно должна делать (какие входные данные она получает, какие выходные данные она возвращает)?

Если да, то верно ли утверждение, что функциональные требования к библиотекам или фреймворкам фактически описываются в их API?

Составляя диаграмму USE CASE для фреймворка или библиотеки - будет ли она дублировать документацию к API?

Answer (score 0):

Функциональные требования являются постановкой задачи к разработчику. В требованиях должны содержаться ответы на все возможные вопросы по задаче.
Если чего то нет в требованиях, то работа делается на усмотрение разработчика.
Функциональные требования состоят из: User story — показывает, чего вы ожидаете от команды разработки
Use cases — показывают сценарии использования фичи
Wireframes — средство визуализации своей идеи
Функциональные требования помогают продакт-менеджеру продумать и четко сформулировать все сценарии взаимодействия пользователя с интерфейсов в рамках задачи.

Чем точнее поставлена задача и чем больше деталей есть у разработчиков до начала работы, тем эффективнее идет работа. Не тратится время на долгую и подчас бессмысленную коммуникацию. В этом случае все стороны в выигрыше: разработчики получают четкое понимание, что и как нужно сделать, а поставщик задачи получает выполненную работу именно в том виде, в каком он ее себе представлял.

Comment: Из вашего ответа, я понял, что уровень абстракции используемый для описания функциональных требований зависит от того, насколько хорошо разбираются все участники в предметной области. Если все участники разбираются в программировании и более узких задачах, которые должна решить библиотека, то допустимо ли в качестве функциональных требований использовать документацию к API? А если нет - то как должны выглядеть такие требования для библиотеки и фреймворка?